# How to find such an isotropic space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms

Suppose $(V,f)$ is a nonsingular orthogonal geometry with dimension $n$, and $W$ is a totally isotropic space with dimension $r$. How to find such a totally isotropic space $N$ 
 with dimension $r$ such that

1)$V=W^\bot  \oplus N$

2)$V=W \oplus H\oplus N$ where $H=W^\bot \cap N^\bot$

In addition, if the first condition holds, then the second one is true.

Suppose there's a base $\{a_1,\dots,a_s,a_{-1},\dots,a_{-(n-s)}\}$ that $f$ under this base is $\begin{pmatrix} I_s& 0\\0&-I_{n-s}\end{pmatrix}$. And suppose $W=\langle a_1+a_{-1},...,a_r+a_{-r}\rangle$. Then how to construct such a $N$? It seems that $N=\langle a_1+a_{-(n-2r+1)}, \dots ,a_r+a_{-(n-r)}\rangle $ satisfies the conditions, but I not pretty sure. Am I wrong or right? If I'm right, then how to prove it? Is there an clearer way to see this? Thanks in advance.

$\textbf{EDIT}$:After reading some suggestions on meta, I realized that I was not explicit with my post and efforts. As I've mentioned above, I $\textbf{seemed}$ to find an $N$ that satisfied the conditions. But when I examined this $N$ in the general case $n$, I found that the calculation was too difficult. So I worked with some simple cases when $n=5$, $r=s=2$ and $n=9$, $r=s=3$. In these cases, the first condition is always satisfied. But as for the second one, it's not clear because the basis of $H$ is really complicated.

So I'm thinking that my answer might be wrong or I chose a "complicated" basis. Sorry that this might be a silly question. Thanks again.

Comment: Is a "non-degenerate orthogonal space"  the same thing a space equipped with a non-degenerate quadratic form/non-degenerate metric?

Comment: And all the sums are *orthogonal*?

Comment: @rschwieb a "non-degenerate orthogonal space" here is a space with non-degenerate metric (or a bilinear function) and this metric (bilinear function) is symmetric.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @Will Jagy These part bascially come from the notes that I took in class. Maybe it's 'defined' by our teacher. We are using Hoffman's linear algebra.

Comment: @Will Jagcy Would you mind edit for me?

Comment: Johnny, I guess you mean a quadratic space. However, my first impression is that your question is impossible for subspaces of total space $V.$  Do your notes mention Witt's Lemma?